# netfilter - iptables-restore file format documentation

Tags: iptables, configuration

What is the file format expected by iptables-restore? Does a description of the format exist?

Comment: I am not sure that the file created by `iptables-save` and consumed on `stdin` by `iptables-restore` is really considered an open API for Iptables. If you want to change the file, you are probably better off using `iptables` itself, not modifying the dump file.

Comment: The trouble is, I am going to be using iptables-apply to safely make changes over ssh. Some changes cannot be made with iptables without risking being locked out.

Comment: Was that edit meant to be helpful, or just boring, @jeff-schaller?

Comment: Both; by not including links or quotes to the research you've already done, saying "I've searched everywhere" doesn't add anything to the question.  Ditto the "you're my only hope" -- as you appear to have made some good progress on your own!  The [tour page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and other [meta discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) suggest a minimum of chit-chat in the question; instead, focus on the technical details.

Comment: OK, I get it now. Thanks for being patient, @JeffSchaller. ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found my answer, sort-of...
As best as I can tell, there is no document. However, in reading the source code I've uncovered how it works.

Lines starting with `#` are for comments and are not parsed.
Blank lines are ignored.
`*` marks the *table* name.
`:` marks the *chain*, followed by the default *policy* and optionally the packet and byte counters.
byte counters can precede a rule.
Rules are exactly as given on the command line less the table name.
Each table section must end with `COMMIT`.

The good news is that the syntax for the actual rules is just as it says in `man iptables`.

```
# iptables-restore format
*<table>
:<chain> <policy> [<packets_count>:<bytes_count>]
<optional_counter><rule>
... more rules ...
COMMIT
```

-

```
# iptables-restore example
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -J ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

Comment: Ha, now how about documentation on the extensions...

Comment: can you explain why `:INPUT DROP [0:0]` does not flush `INPUT` but `:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]` does flush `DOCKER-USER`, with `iptables-restore --noflush`?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry. Might be worth posting a new question.