# ufw iptables jump rule errors with "Could not load logging rules"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, ufw

I'm trying to set up iptables rules in ufw, but I seem to be misunderstanding how it works. I couldn't find any solid documentation apart from the general syntax described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400163/netfilter-iptables-restore-file-format-documentation). Here is a simplified version of my problem:

In `/etc/ufw/after.rules` I append:

```
*filter
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:FOO-CHAIN - [0:0]
-A FOO-CHAIN -j ufw-user-input
-A FOO-CHAIN -j DROP
COMMIT
```

The idea - in `FOO-CHAIN`, allow only packets which have been allowed by `ufw allow`, otherwise drop.

The problem - when I `ufw reload` once, the rules are applied, but on the second reload, I start getting a constant `ERROR: Could not load logging rules`. The only fix I found was to flush the whole table (`iptables -F && iptables -X`).

Follow-up questions:

- Using `ufw-user-forward` instead makes no errors on reloading. Why is that?
- Why do I have to define the chain via `:ufw-user-input - [0:0]`, or otherwise face `ERROR: No such file or directory`? Since this is the `after.rules` file, it should have ran after `user.rules`, which means `ufw-user-input` should have been defined already. If I change the jump to `ufw-before-input`, I can omit defining it, and I don't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, I discover that UFW internally check the existence of `ufw-user-input` chain in iptables for knowing if ufw is in an enabled or disabled state.

Using `ufw-user-input` in `-A FOO-CHAIN -j ufw-user-input` will prevent `ufw-user-input` do be deleted when you do `ufw reload` or `ufw disable`, the chain will still be there because iptables did not accept the change. Then UFW state will be mess up and even `ufw status` will be broken.

You need to ensure your rules are correctly cleaned up after `ufw disable` or `ufw reload`.

The simplest way is to add `iptables -F FOO-CHAIN || true` or something similar to delete all the lines mentioning `ufw-user-input` chain in `/etc/ufw/before.init`.

#### `/etc/ufw/before.init`

```bsh
set -e

case "$1" in
start)
    # typically required
    ;;
stop)
    # typically required
    iptables -F FOO-CHAIN || true
    # You may want to add other lines here to reset your chain in a desirable state if UFW is disabled like 
    # iptables -A FOO-CHAIN -j RETURN || true
    ;;
status)
    # optional
    ;;
flush-all)
    # optional
    ;;
*)
    echo "'$1' not supported"
    echo "Usage: before.init {start|stop|flush-all|status}"
    ;;
esac
```

Don't forget to make `before.init` executable with `chmod +x /etc/ufw/before.init`.

I confirm you need `:ufw-user-input - [0:0]`, it's due to the internal of UFW, I think `ufw-user-input` is inserted after the `after.rules`.